# strip html of each child element

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

let say i have dirty html like so...

```
let dirty = `
<pre>
    pre tag with <b>html</b>
</pre>
<pre>
    another pre tag with <b>html</b>
</pre>
`
```

i need to strip html from each child of pre tag...

im doing this...

```
let $ = cheerio.load(dirty)
$('pre').each(function() {
    let text = $(this).text()
    console.warn(text) // html are stripped
    return `<pre>${text}</pre>`
});
console.log($.html()) // html are not stripped
```

what i missed..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('pre').each(function() {
    let text = $(this).text()
    // You need to inject cleaned string into the DOM
    $(this).html(text)
});

console.log($('div').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <pre>
    pre tag with <b>html</b>
  </pre>
  <pre>
    another pre tag with <b>html</b>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note that while you technically can delimit multi-line strings with backticks, it's completely unsupported in IE, so cannot reliably be used. You need to use quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) instead.

The issue with your logic is that you define the `text` varaiable in the each loop, but do nothing with it, as returning from `each()` is redundant.

To fix the problem you can simply use the `text()` method to strip out any child HTML from the given element. Try this:

```js
let dirty = '<pre>pre tag with <b>html</b></pre><pre>another pre tag with <b>html</b></pre>';

$('body').append(dirty);
$('pre').text(function(i, t) {
  return t;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Pete you're right, however IE does not support it at all, so I think it'd be better to remind that in case js code is meant to run on client side

Comment: The statement is not true @smarber, also, the question is about nodejs

Comment: Well, it originally had a jQuery tag before you edited Node in to it, for some unknown reason, as the OP gave no mention of Node whatsoever

Comment: Yes they did @RoryMcCrossan. The usage of [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) is clearly nodejs - However you're also right, it's the OPs fault - however the question has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: ... I removed my downvote after you changed your first sentence in the answer.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually assign the new html, right now you don't set the html to something else. Below will work

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
let dirty = `
<pre>
    pre tag with <b>html</b>
</pre>
<pre>
    another pre tag with <b>html</b>
</pre>
`;
let $ = cheerio.load(dirty);
$("pre").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text());
});
console.log($.html());
```